# Automation tool for Mobile apps and Silverlight app

Tags: android, ios, silverlight, testing, automation

I have one application available in 3 platforms:

1) Silverlight,

2) Android,

3) iOS.

Is there any **free** tool using which I can perform automated testing? I found one good automation tool [appium](http://appium.io/slate/en/master/?csharp#introduction-to-appium), but it seems  to support only Android and iOS. Is there any tool for all three platforms I mentioned above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I daresay that there is no one solution for all your platforms.

Selenium allows to test it separately:

- [Selendroid](http://selendroid.io/) - Android platform

  [ios-driver](http://ios-driver.github.io/ios-driver/) - iOS platform

  [silverlight-selenium](https://code.google.com/p/silverlight-selenium/) - Silverlight platform